# Div element blocking access to markers

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have an issue with a positioned DIV over a Google Maps instance.  In this case the DIV is causing problems with being able to access the map, from where it starts at the top to the bottom.  It's taking up the entire width of the map, when it should stop at the borders of the green square.

You are not able to interact with the Google Map except at the very bottom once the green square ends.

You can see what I mean here:

http://www.christielakekids.com/newsite/index.php  (scroll down to the map about halfway down the page)

```
<div class="map_block">

            <div id="map-canvas"></div>

            <div class="map_block_in">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="map_block_left">
                        <p>Check out what we're up to in the community!</p>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span><img src="/_images/new/blue_circle.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""></span>
                                    <small>OUR PROGRAMS</small>
                                    <em class="clear"></em>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span><img src="/_images/new/red_circle.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""></span>
                                    <small>OUR SPONSORS</small>
                                    <em class="clear"></em>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span><img src="/_images/new/orange_circle.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""></span>
                                    <small>EVENTS</small>
                                    <em class="clear"></em>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>


.map_block_left                             { float:left; display:inline-block; width:381px; background:url(../../../_images/new/green_bg.png) repeat left top; margin:140px 0 0 0; padding:80px 0 65px 0;}
.map_block_left p                           { font-family: 'GothamBookRegular'; font-size:20px; color:#FFF; line-height:25px; padding:0 40px 15px 50px;}
.map_block_left ul                          { display:block; margin:0 0 0 50px;}
.map_block_left ul li                       { display:block; margin:0 0 14px 0;}
.map_block_left ul li a                     { display:inline-block;}
.map_block_left ul li a span                { float:left; display:inline-block;}
.map_block_left ul li a small               { float:left; display:inline-block;font-family: 'GothamMedium'; font-size:20px; color:#FFF; line-height:25px; padding:2px 0 0 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following style:

```
.map_block_in {pointer-events: none;}
```

and you should be able to interact with the map underneath

[I should point out this is only available for newer browsers though](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

Or for a more cross-browser solution, you could just add:

```
.map_block_in,
.map_block_in .container {height:0;}
```

Answer (score -1):

yeah i got your problem you can do one thing try with Z-index of googlemap code in css with more than divison

Comment: Punctuation, please, and an actual CSS snippet would make this answer more valuable.